# Create TZ string from Python ZoneInfo

Tags: python, timezone, zoneinfo

I can easily get a `ZoneInfo` object for the time zone of my choice:

```
import zoneinfo
ct = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Chicago')
```

I need to create a `TZ` environment variable for an embedded system that doesn't have a timezone database, so I can't simply reuse the location string as you might do on a regular Linux system.  I need to embed the actual daylight savings transition rules in the string, for my example it would look like:

```
TZ=CST06CDT05,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2
```

I haven't been able to find any way to build that string.  It doesn't bother me that the string might become obsolete if the rules change.

This also needs to work for time zones outside the U.S.

If there's a better way to get the information than using ZoneInfo, I'm willing to entertain answers for that too.

Comment: I don't have a Python answer for you, but you could reverse-engineer my C# library code [here](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter/tree/main/src/TimeZoneConverter.Posix).  The key thing to remember is you can only have exactly zero or two transition rules in a POSIX `TZ` string.  You can fake a single transition easily, but you can't have three or more, and you can't represent rules from past years.  For IoT devices, it works well for getting the _current_ time, as long as you can call home occasionally to get a new TZ string when the rules change.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot that I did this in JavaScript back in the Moment.js days also.  You might prefer reverse engineering from that instead.  https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314#issuecomment-198226333

Comment: There's also a small paragraph about POSIX time zone strings in the `timezone` tag wiki, towards the bottom.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info

Answer (score 0):

POSIX TZ strings can be found at the end of [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) files (version 2 or higher), see [RFC 8536, sect. TZif footer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8536#section-3.3). They are newline-separated from the rest, so you can obtain them for instance like

```py
from pathlib import Path
import zoneinfo

zones = zoneinfo.available_timezones()

# path to IANA tz db on your system, adjust if needed
basepath = Path("/usr/share/zoneinfo/")

for z in zones:
    with open(basepath / z, "rb") as fobj:
        content = fobj.readlines()
    print(z, content[-1].decode("ASCII").strip("\n"))
```

which gives for example

```
...
Australia/North ACST-9:30
Europe/Gibraltar CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3
America/Bogota <-05>5
America/Los_Angeles PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
Asia/Ujung_Pandang WITA-8
```

Note that this only works "out of the box" on systems that ship with the IANA db (Mac, Linux). If you're on Windows, you'll first have to obtain the IANA database. You should be able to use the database version provided by the [tzdata](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/) package. The database itself lives in `[Python-version]\\Lib\\site-packages\\tzdata\\zoneinfo`. The code to obtain the POSIX strings could then look something like

```py
basepath = Path("C:\\Users\\username\\[path-to-Python]\\[Python-version]\\Lib\\site-packages\\tzdata\\zoneinfo")
zoneinfo.reset_tzpath(to=(basepath,))
zones = zoneinfo.available_timezones()

# now iterate zones as shown in the first snippet.
```

Alternatively, you can build the db yourself, Paul Eggert's [tz repo](https://github.com/eggert/tz) has instructions on how to do so. You'll need `make` and a `C`-compiler for the utilities.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned in the question, I need this to work in Windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom ...and I should have phrased the last sentence differently. Of course you can do the same on Windows, but you need to get the IANA database first. The easiest way is probably to use `tzdata`, see edit.